# Redundantly tagging engine theory questions with the "engine" tag

Tags: discussion, retagging

Looking back, it seems a bit silly that we've tagged a lot of the [engine-theory](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine-theory) questions with an [engine](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) tag as well.

At the moment there are 96 out of 157 questions affected by this. I'm going to start by retagging my own questions.

Comment: I don't see an issue with having both tags involved in a question, especially if the question doesn't have all five tags filled out. It helps the meta data of the site to do so.